# JavaBridge errno=10054 Closed by Remotehost

Tags: java, php, php-java-bridge

I am implementing a Java Application (not a dynamic web project) for a server.
This should be an UDP listener running in background calling PHP for each UDP datagram to evaluate the UDP data.

I got a look into JavaBridge and it seems perfect for my intention. Running a java class invoking a PHP file, sending parameters and getting parameters works perfectly when I run it as a jsp on the server.
But running it as a simple Java application with a main method I get an error every second time, I am running it.
The Java code looks like this:

```
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine instance = manager.getEngineByName("php-invocable");
    try {
        URI remotePhpApp = new URI("http", null, "127.0.0.1", 8081, "/JavaBridge/java/JavaProxy.php", null, null);
          ByteArrayOutputStream sharedResource = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          Integer nr = 42;
          instance.put("nr", nr);
          instance.put("sharedResource", sharedResource);
          Object result = instance.eval(new URLReader(remotePhpApp.toURL()));
          String res = result.toString();
          System.out.println ("Found " + sharedResource.toString() + " entries in database");
          sharedResource.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Could not evaluate script: "+ex);
    }
```

The console output shows an IOExcption. The Tomcat server displays:
PHP Notice: fwrite(): send of 6 bytes failed with errno=10054...pointing on the Java.inc line 815

...but only every second time. Has someone an idea?

Answer (score 0):

So finally, I found someting. Well not the answer for the problem, but a solution.
Instead of the URLReader I used a FileReader with the local path to the PHP file.
Now there is nothing about a lost connection and I can use JavaBridge in my Java application without errors.